# Figures numbering in arabic while chapters in roman

Tags: floats, numbering, chapters

I have an issue with the numbering of the figures. I have my chapters numbered in Roman thanks to the command `\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}` (Chapter I, Chapter II etc.). Therefore, I would like the figures to be numbered by chapters with arabic numbers like Figure 1.2 for the second figure of Chapter I.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks, Pierre

Comment: `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}` in the preamble. Do you really want an arabic chapter number for the figure?

Comment: Hi @ChristianHupfer, it works perfectly well (ps you just have forgotten a \ before `thefigure`

Comment: I corrected it some minutes ago :-P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `figure` environment uses the `figure` counter, which is defined to be reset when the `chapter` is increased (e.g. each time a new chapter is begun.)

This will also lead to use the chapter counter prefix (here Roman) in the figure counter output, i.e. `\thefigure` is `\thechapter.\arabic{figure}` most likely.

If this is not wanted, the `\thefigure` command must be redefined, say, to

```
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
```

Here is minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}


\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\chapter{First}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Another dummy figure}
\end{figure}


\chapter{Second}

\begin{figure}
\caption{A dummy figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Another dummy figure}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```