# Arabic figure numbering while chapters in roman

Tags: floats, numbering, chapters, subfiles

I want the numbering on my figures to appear as e.g. "1.1" and not "I.1". In my setup, I have made a `subfiles` configuration like so:

MAIN.TEX:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\subfile{chap/ch1.tex} 
\end{document}
```

and in CH1.TEX:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{first}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{A dummy figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Now, in the subfile, the numbering on the figure is "1.1" as wanted, but in the mainfile it is displayed "I.1". I have tried deleting the .aux files for both documents and recompiling, but it doesn't work. The above code comes from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/274849/figures-numbering-in-arabic-while-chapters-in-roman).

I am using TexLive 2014 with TeXmaker 4.5 under Windows 7.

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:

I found out where the error in my code is hidden. In my main.tex I have putten a `\mainmatter` before calling `\subfile{chap/ch1}`, and that changes the label from `1.1` to `I.1`. Is it possible to somehow override this behaviour of the `\mainmatter` macro?

Comment: I get `1.1` in the mainfile. I think, your `main.tex` file is missing `\usepackage{subfiles}`. I find your numbering style confusing, too. If you want to display chapter numbers with Roman figures, this should be applied for the `\thefigure` as well

Comment: I have loaded the subfiles package in my document, sorry for the confusing code above! I am not sure what you mean by applying the same procedure to the chapter numbers as well?

Comment: Please `\meaning\thefigure` after `\begin{document}` and see whether it reports `long macro:->\arabic {chapter}.\arabic figure`

Comment: It does report "long macro:->\arabic {chapter}.\arabic figure" when I put the "\meaning\thefigure" code in the subfile.

Comment: In the mainfile, it displays `macro:->\@nameuse {thechapter}.\arabic {figure}`

Comment: It should display the same version I posted in the `main.tex` file, not in the `subfile`. `\@nameuse` looks strange! Are you really using the code you posted?

Comment: Actually, I find those `subfiles`, `import` etc. packages not really useful, but that's my personal opinion

Comment: The above is not exactly it, but it ought to be enough to reproduce the problem... I am trying now to just compile the the above code, to see whether there are problems with some of the other packages I am using.

Comment: Hmm.. I have tried to comment out a significant part of the code to try to find where it goes wrong, but it hasn't changed anything. I am using Texlive 2014 on Windows 7 with TexMaker.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing `\usepackage{subfiles}`.  Without it, it won't compile.  With it, everything works fine.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\Roman{chapter}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{figure}}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}
    \subfile{ch1.tex} 

    Figure \ref{dummy} and \ref{dumber}.

    \begin{figure}
        \caption{A dummy figure\label{dumber}}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\chapter{first}
\begin{figure}
  \caption{A dummy figure\label{dummy}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have loaded the subfiles package in my original code in my document, but it still displays `1.1` in the subfiles and `I.1` in the mainfile.

Comment: Hmm, which versions?  Use `\listfiles` in the preamble?

Comment: I haven't used `\listfiles`. What does that do?

Comment: It lists the packages that you have.  There may have been bug fixes.